# Error mysql update command in php code

Tags: php, mysql

My php file performs a number of database actions including the one below. This action however results in a SQL error:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10:07:28 WHERE
>   id=11' at line 1"

The php debugger shows the $sqlquery value: `"UPDATE AGREEMENTS SET approval=2013-11-22 10:07:28 WHERE id=11 "`

Some other SQL UPDATE commands in the php code have the exact same syntax and are executed correctly (but do not include date variables). I suspect the problem relates to the date format, but I dont know how to fix this (?)

PHP code:

```
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

$sqlquery ="UPDATE AGREEMENTS "
                    . "SET approval=".$currentdate." "
                    . "WHERE id=".$agreementids[$i]." ";

$db->UpdateDBRecord($sqlquery);
```

Comment: Try enclosing date value in quotes

Comment: you have used unbalanced quotes, please check them....also, why have you concatenated the string which was not required....` AGREEMENTS " . "SET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add single qoutes around date variable

```
$sqlquery ="UPDATE AGREEMENTS "
                . "SET approval='".$currentdate."' "
                . "WHERE id=".$agreementids[$i]." ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sqlquery ='"UPDATE AGREEMENTS SET approval="'.$currentdate.'" WHERE id="'.$agreementids[$i].'""';
```

Answer (score 0):

incorrect use of double quotes in the end of query and not using single quote for comparing the dates, your sql query should be

```
$sqlquery ="UPDATE AGREEMENTS SET approval='".$currentdate."' WHERE id='".$agreementids[$i]."'";
```